# How to work GPGPU or GPU Processing (CUDAFY) in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

So I'm trying to work out how to use my GPU for processing in vb.net. I've found what looks to be a great tutorial for c# (check it out seem simple enough for c# users). Anyways my knowledge of c# is so poor I'm having trouble moving things from c# to vb.net.

Here's the link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202792/Using-Cudafy-for-GPGPU-Programming-in-NET

If anyone can convert this to vb.net code (that makes sense) then that'd be great. Otherwise if someone could just give me a really simple vb.net example of running vector operations on the GPU based on this tutorial (or anything else) then that would probably be better! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many VB.NET to C# covertors available online
http://converter.telerik.com/

For example:

```
CudafyModule km = CudafyModule.TryDeserialize(typeof(Program).Name);
if (km == null || !km.TryVerifyChecksums())
{
    km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(typeof(Program));
    km.Serialize();
}
```

becomes

```
Dim km As CudafyModule = CudafyModule.TryDeserialize(GetType(Program).Name)
If km Is Nothing OrElse Not km.TryVerifyChecksums() Then
    km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(GetType(Program))
    km.Serialize()
End If
```

There are also applications like this: http://www.elegancetech.com/CSVB/CSVB.aspx?src=12

but the above option is free and will help you undestand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nahum and talonmies! From my understanding the usefulness of GPGPU is vector processing. So could you give an example of this? I'm still having trouble with some getting anything useful performed. I'll post my code thus far in a little while (needs tidying up first).

Comment: Sorry I have no clue about GPGPU except that it is good for vector processing. good luck with that!